# Get true limit of plot area of an Axes in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axes

I'd like to find out the exact extents of the data inside a matplotlib Axes object; i.e., their highest and lowest x-values, and highest and lowest y-values. (My specific application only needs me to be able to determine the highest x-value with an error of less than 0.5, but I'm curious about the general case.)

You're supposed to use `Axes.get_xlim()` and `.get_ylim()` to get the extent of an Axes object, but due to the margins, these limits will be slightly outside the data limits. For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(range(100), range(100))
ax = plt.gca()
print(ax.get_xlim()) # prints (-4.95, 103.95)
```

The margins are given by `Axes.margins()` as a fraction of the axes, so what if we subtract those? We end up underestimating the limits a little:

```
xlim, xmargin = ax.get_xlim(), ax.margins()[0]
width = xlim[1] - xlim[0]
lower_xlim = xlim[0] + width*xmargin # 0.495, should be 0
upper_xlim = xlim[1] - width*xmargin # 98.505, should be 99
```

With trial and error, we find that if we multiply the correcting term by `10/11`, we finally hit our mark:

```
lower_xlim = xlim[0] + width*xmargin*10/11 # 0.
upper_xlim = xlim[1] - width*xmargin*10/11 # 99.
```

Upon closer inspection with different data ranges and margin sizes, it turns out that the actual factor is:

```
lower_xlim = xlim[0] + width*5/110 # 0.
upper_xlim = xlim[1] - width*5/110 # 99.
```

Very bizarre, but it works very well. Except... what if we're using `Axes.imshow()` instead of `Axes.plot()`? The plot doesn't have margins in that case (if `Axes.use_sticky_edges()` is `True`, which is the default), but the result of `Axes.margins()` is the same either way. Also, this might be messed up by the addition of non-data Artists such as text boxes outside of the current bounds. (Maybe. I've never tried it.)

I know that a foolproof way to find the data limits would be to iterate through all of the data in the Axes object and compute their maxima and minima. This can be done by finding out the Axes object's artists with `Axes.get_children()`, and grabbing the data from those that provide the method `.get_data()`. But this is very computationally expensive.

Is there a better way? Or is my 5/110 hack the next best thing? Why is the 5/110 factor even required? Why doesn't it depend on `xmargin`? (Should I call `Axes.autoscale()` first?)

Comment: I doubt there is a unified approach to it, given that I can set xlim to (-2, -1) in your example and no object will be plotted. And what would be the minimum value for a bar plot? The center, because it is the actual value? The left border of the left bar?

Comment: Oh, good point, lims can be set. That messes everything up. For a bar plot, it would be the centers; I'm looking for the limits of the data going into the plot, regardless of what kind of plot it is.

Comment: There is no such a thing since the plot contains artists, not data. You need to know the relationship between artists and data and that depends on the type of artists and then some more things --what if the bar plot is an histogram? The relevant x data is not the centers but the bin edges.

Comment: @Goyo The intent of my question is to just ask about a shortcut around collecting the data from each artist and then getting the min/max. It's true that the relationship between that data and the plot limits is very nontrivial, so you can't use the plot limits except in special cases, but I guess I figured the plot has to keep track of those numbers somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

this should work properly:

```
lower_xlim = xlim[0] + (0.5 * xmargin) / (0.5 + xmargin) * width
upper_xlim = xlim[1] - (0.5 * xmargin) / (0.5 + xmargin) * width
```